# Umbraco 7 dynamic menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

Good day!
working on Umbraco and struggling to create dynamic menu in Umbraco.
The menu li's should be called using menuName.

It works for first loop (static menu called item.menuName), but does not work in second - node.menuName. node.Name is works, but .menuName does not. Why?

Thank you!

```
    var homePage = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First();
    var menuItems = homePage.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");

<ul class="menu">

    @foreach (var item in menuItems)
    {
        var childrenItems = item.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");
        <li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == item.Id ? "sel" : null)">
            <a href="@item.Url"><h4>@item.menuName</h4></a>
            @createSubmenu(childrenItems, item.Id)
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@helper createSubmenu(IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> nodes, int? parentId) {
    if (nodes.Count() > 0){
        <ul>
        @foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            var childrenItems = node.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");
            <li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == node.Id ? "sel" : null)">
                <a href="@node.Url"><h5>@node.menuName</h5></a>
                @createSubmenu(childrenItems, node.Id)
            </li>
        }
        </ul>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not use strongly styled views, the `CurrentPage` property of the `UmbracoTemplatePage` is a `dynamic` meaning that `@item.menuItem` is accessible.

Your `createSubmenu` helper however, casts the dynamic's to an `IPublishedContent` which does not have a member `menuName` available. You will need to use the `GetPropertyValue` method:

```
@helper createSubmenu(IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> nodes, int? parentId)
{
    if (nodes.Count() > 0)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                var childrenItems = node.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");
                <li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == node.Id ? "sel" : null)">
                    <a href="@node.Url"><h5>@node.GetPropertyValue("menuName")</h5></a>
                    @createSubmenu(childrenItems, node.Id)
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
```